# Why does Laravel load belongsTo withDefault values even if there is relation set?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, belongs-to

I have a model, Project, that I am eager loading relations in the Http/Controller.

The problem is that the withDefault closure on the belongsTo Relation in the model always fires, regardless of if there is an actual relation to eager load, resulting in many pointless queries and strange side effects.

This doesn't seem like it should be expected behaviour - is there any way to stop it calling withDefault() unless it actually needs to?

To clarify:

`return $project->loadMissing('address');`

From the model:

```
    public function address(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsTo(Address::class, 'address_id')
            ->withDefault(function() {
                // This will always trigger
            });
    }
```

withDefault triggers always, regardless of the state of the actual relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is the default behavior.

The callback function inside `withDefault` function will get executed every time Laravel sets the `BelongsTo` relation of a model.

Take a look at the [initRelation function](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo.php#L150) of laravel's core `BelongsTo` class

```
public function initRelation(array $models, $relation)
{
    foreach ($models as $model) {
        $model->setRelation($relation, $this->getDefaultFor($model));
    }

    return $models;
}
```

And if you look at the `getDefaultFor` and `withDefault` functions [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/SupportsDefaultModels.php#L32)

```
/**
 * Return a new model instance in case the relationship does not exist.
 *
 * @param  \Closure|array|bool  $callback
 * @return $this
 */
public function withDefault($callback = true)
{
    $this->withDefault = $callback;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get the default value for this relation.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $parent
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
 */
protected function getDefaultFor(Model $parent)
{
    if (! $this->withDefault) {
        return;
    }

    $instance = $this->newRelatedInstanceFor($parent);

    if (is_callable($this->withDefault)) {
        return call_user_func($this->withDefault, $instance, $parent) ?: $instance;
    }

    if (is_array($this->withDefault)) {
        $instance->forceFill($this->withDefault);
    }

    return $instance;
}
```

You will observe that if `$this->withDefault` is a callable, it will always be executed; there isn't a direct way to conditionally trigger its execution.

I would recommend avoiding running heavy tasks like database queries inside that function, as it could lead to performance problems, especially when processing a large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, when say 'eager' you executed your query using 'with' function?

Example:

```
$query = $this->model->newQuery();
$query->with('cargos');
$query->with('tasks');
...
...
/** @var Order $order */
$order = $query->get()->first();
```

Comment: Not quite, using ->load()

Comment: try using with(..) as I wrote in example and then try to access the property like $order->cargos and look if the system makes sql call.

Comment: With doesn't seem to make a difference - still has the same problem.

Comment: If you pull only one object and you have one relation for your object, then using 'with' doesn't  makes difference. You always will have two sql: 1) for main object 2) for relation.

But.

If you have array of objects. Then without using 'with', say you will extract array with 10 main objects. Then for each of these 10 lazy loader will make one sql each.

But if you use 'with' for your first query, then you will have TOTALY two queryies.

Comment: The problem is it calling withDefault() even if there is a relation.

Comment: What happens when you access your 'address' property twice?

I expect that first time your withDefault function will be called, but should not be called second time.

Comment: The problem is it shouldn't be called at all - the relation exists.

Answer (score -1):

In your Project model, you can define a boolean property to track whether the relationship was eager loaded. Then, you can override the load and loadMissing methods in your model to set this flag when loading relationships.

```
protected $relationLoaded = false;

public function load($relations)
{
    parent::load($relations);
    $this->relationLoaded = true;
    return $this;
}

public function loadMissing($relations)
{
    parent::loadMissing($relations);
    $this->relationLoaded = true;
    return $this;
}
```

Then you can check in your closure if relation was eager loaded or not.

```
public function address(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this
        ->belongsTo(Address::class, 'address_id')
        ->withDefault(function () {
            if (!$this->relationLoaded) {
                // This will only trigger when the relationship is not eager loaded
            }
        });
}
```